# Mapping variable argument LISP function to C function - C

Tags: c, lisp, interpreter

I am developing a custom LISP interpreter. It won't support defining functions like in LISP, instead all functions are mapped to C functions. When it sees an expression like,

```
(substr 'input '1 '1)
```

it knows to call internal `substr` function and return the result.

Now I am planning to implement a `message` function which supports basic formatting and writes the output to `stdout`. Something like,

```
(message "Hello, %s" name)
```

`%s` will be replaced with value in variable `name`.

Current plan is to directly pass the format and arguments to functions like `printf`. In that way, I can support all formats that `printf` supports. But problem comes with variable number of arguments. One way to do will be something like,

```
if(argcount == 1)
   /* call printf with one arg */
else if(argcount == 2)
   /* call printf with two arg */
....
```

This works, but I am wondering is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a way to do this. The reason is that the number of parameters to your lisp function is only known at runtime, but the number of arguments to a C function must be known at compile time.

This includes va_lists unless you want to hack at them in some kind of platform specific way.

The best you can really do is write a function in C which is capable of looping through the arguments one at a time and doing something with them. The only way I can see around this is to not only store a function pointer for each of your internal functions, but to also store a "calling convention" which will give information about whether it takes parameters in the ordinary way or whether it finishes with the equivalent of a va_list.

Functions like printf would have a wrapper, printf_wrapper, say, and you'd store a function pointer to the wrapper. This wrapper would accept the format string as an ordinary parameter, followed by a list or array of other parameters (roughly analogous to a va_list).

You might indicate that printf_wrapper finishes with a parameter that expects a list by specifying the calling conventions for the printf_wrapper function as "va_list_type", meaning that it takes the usual fixed parameters, and that all remaining parameters must be bundled up and supplied to it as a list.

Of course writing a printf_wrapper function which can split up and parse a format string into multiple format strings is a bit of work. Here's an example of where I did precisely this so that I could add my own custom format specifiers:

https://github.com/wbhart/bsdnt/blob/v0.26/helper.c

Answer (score 0):

Have your C function take parameters somewhat like `argc/argv`. That is, take a parameter specifying the number of parameters, and then a pointer to a list of pointers for each parameter.

Comment: I understand this. But problem is I have to use `printf` or similar existing functions internally.

Comment: Well, `vprintf` needs `va_list`. Do you think I can create it from the arguments?

Comment: @Appu Yes, but it will involve knowing the implementation details of va_list for your platform. But it is a data structure like any other and can be made on the fly.

Comment: @Conrad..I don't think creating `va_list` manually is a good idea and I couldn't think of doing it in a platform independent way.

Comment: Fine, or implement `printf` yourself. Do you like that idea any better?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better than an *if-else* chain would be a switch.

```
switch(argcount){
    case 1: printf(arg[0]); break;
    case 2: printf(arg[0],arg[1]); break;
    //etc.
}
```